# Default schema not working with Windows user

Tags: sql-server, schema, default

We are running into an issue with an install, receiving the error `"Invalid object name ..."`. 
It does not seem to be using the default schema assignment set on the Windows user. 
I have set up a test in our AdventureWorks2012 database and am receiving the same result. 
When I connect to the instance with the Windows account (set up with a default schema of "Person" in the AdventureWorks2012 database), and execute the statement `SELECT * FROM Address`, I receive the same error `Invalid object name Address`. 
Next I created a SQL login, mapped the login to the AdventureWorks2012 database and again set the default schema to "Person". When I connect to the instance using the SQL login, and execute the command `SELECT * FROM Address`, the query is successful and returns results. 
I am experiencing the same outcome in both SQL 2012 and SQL 2014. Can anyone help me out with why the default schema setting is not working with the Windows user?

Comment: Is the Windows user a sysadmin role member (i.e. SELECT USER returns 'dbo')?

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on the default schema anyway. You should always specify the schema in your queries. Consider how much work it would be if the default schema becomes changed at some point in the future.

Comment: I second what @SeanLange says. But I also love a good mystery. Does the Windows user in question belong to multiple Windows groups? If so, they are likely getting their default schema from one of the other groups to which they belong.

Comment: I tried the user as a member of the server sysadmin role, and without the membership of the sysadmin role - didn't make a difference in the outcome.

Comment: As far as the "don't rely on the default schema" statements - this is part of an upgrade of an application and we have no control over how it is written.  The vendor allows the customer to create any schema name they want, build their objects using that schema and then the default schema setting allows the installation/upgrade process to locate the objects.  This is one of many set ups that have used this process in the past and the first time I have run into any issues.  I'm wondering now if some issue has been introduced with a cumulative update as we keep our environments pretty current.

Comment: As far as membership in other Windows roles, that would be a no.  The Windows user is a specific "worker" account that performs the connection from the application to the database. The only group it is a member of is "Domain Users".

Comment: I see that it is documented that you cannot use default schema on a user that is a member of the sysadmin role - so that explains why that test didn't work.  Still wondering why it doesn't work for a Windows user that is not a member of the sysadmin server role, but does work for the SQL authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my issue.  It appears that the membership in the database role db_owner also defaults to dbo schema as once I removed the db_owner database role the default schema assignment kicked in and the query completed successfully.

Thank you to all that considered my issue.